# Compound with Render Props pattern TypeScript issue

Tags: reactjs, typescript, design-patterns

I defined `BodyProps` type in `Table.Body` component where I know for now that I will receive two interfaces of data - `Cabin` and `CabinReservation`. I defined in `BodyProps`, `data` as a union of those two interfaces as I assumed it would guarantee safety and as the Compound component is highly reusable it will accept those two interfaces in different situations without any problems. Now in the `BookingTable` when I'm passing into `render` prop pattern how I would display the passed data using `BookingRow` component where inside of it I defined its `BookingRowProps` type interface where `booking` is assigned to `CabinReservation` as I will only use this data here, it spits error in previously mentioned `render` that passed `booking` prop is `Type 'CabinReservation | Cabin' is not assignable to type 'CabinReservation'.`. Do I need to also define a union in `BookingRow` to pass the issue or is there a different, better approach? I still learning best practices in defining types with TypeScript so every piece of advice will be appreciated.

```
Type 'Cabin | CabinReservation' is not assignable to type 'CabinReservation'.
  Type 'Cabin' is missing the following properties from type 'CabinReservation': startDate, endDate, numNights, numGuests, and 4 more.ts(2322)
```

### BookingRow component

```
type BookingRowProps = {
  booking: CabinReservation;
};

function BookingRow({
  booking: {
    id: bookingId,
    created_at,
    startDate,
    endDate,
    numNights,
    numGuests,
    totalPrice,
    status,
    guests: { fullName: guestName, email },
    cabins: { name: cabinName },
  },
}: BookingRowProps) {
  const statusToTagName = {
    unconfirmed: 'blue',
    'checked-in': 'green',
    'checked-out': 'silver',
  };

  return (
    <Table.Row>
      <Cabin>{cabinName}</Cabin>

      <Stacked>
        <span>{guestName}</span>
        <span>{email}</span>
      </Stacked>

      <Stacked>
        <span>
          {isToday(new Date(startDate))
            ? 'Today'
            : formatDistanceFromNow(startDate)}{' '}
          &rarr; {numNights} night stay
        </span>
        <span>
          {format(new Date(startDate), 'MMM dd yyyy')} &mdash;{' '}
          {format(new Date(endDate), 'MMM dd yyyy')}
        </span>
      </Stacked>

      <Tag type={statusToTagName[status]}>{status.replace('-', ' ')}</Tag>

      <Amount>{formatCurrency(totalPrice)}</Amount>
    </Table.Row>
  );
}

export default BookingRow;
```

### BookingTable component

```
function BookingTable() {
  const { bookings, isLoading } = useBookings();

  if (isLoading) return <Spinner />;
  if (bookings.length === 0) return <Empty resourceName="bookings" />;

  return (
    <Menus>
      <Table columns="0.6fr 2fr 2.4fr 1.4fr 1fr 3.2rem">
        <Table.Header>
          <div>Cabin</div>
          <div>Guest</div>
          <div>Dates</div>
          <div>Status</div>
          <div>Amount</div>
          <div></div>
        </Table.Header>

        <Table.Body
          data={bookings}
          render={booking => <BookingRow key={booking.id} booking={booking} />}
        />
      </Table>
    </Menus>
  );
}
```

### Table Compound component

```
type StyledCommonRow = {
  columns: string | null;
};

type TableProps = {
  columns: string;
  children: React.ReactNode;
};

type HeaderProps = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
};

type RowProps = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
};

type BodyProps = {
  data: Cabin[] | CabinReservation[];
  render: (data: Cabin | CabinReservation) => React.ReactNode;
};

export default function Table({ columns, children }: TableProps) {
  return (
    <TableContext.Provider value={{ columns }}>
      <StyledTable role="table">{children}</StyledTable>
    </TableContext.Provider>
  );
}

function Header({ children }: HeaderProps) {
  const { columns } = useTableContext();

  return (
    <StyledHeader role="row" columns={columns} as="header">
      {children}
    </StyledHeader>
  );
}
function Row({ children }: RowProps) {
  const { columns } = useTableContext();

  return (
    <StyledRow role="row" columns={columns}>
      {children}
    </StyledRow>
  );
}

function Body({ data, render }: BodyProps) {
  return <StyledBody>{data.map(render)}</StyledBody>;
}
```